# Delete unwanted file from a LUN

Tags: lun

I have a SAN environment with LUNs used only for saving documents (. doc, jpg, mp3, xls etc.).
I would like to know the best way to delete from these LUN  to temporary file  word, file thumb, ~ tmp, etc..
For desktop PCs i use software like WiseDiskCleaner.
thanks
Jack Barrier

Comment: You do `find FOLDER 2> /dev/null | grep ~$ | xargs rm` (get all entry names | filter those ended with '~' | wipe them). Back it up and good luck.

Comment: What make/model is your SAN? How is it presenting its storage for these LUNs? Are you presenting it as block storage to an intermediate file server or are you using something like CIFS to present the storage directly to clients?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't delete files directly from a SAN. The LUNs are attached to servers and you would  use a utility on the server to perform that operation on the LUN

Comment: so for example a utility like WiseDisk cleaner